# How to add box shadow to webkit-box-reflect?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

[image]I am trying to add shadow to my button's reflection below. I have added a pic of the button to this question. Hope there is a solution :)

HTML
 Button

```
[![CSS
/* From uiverse.io by @SylviaMakuch */
button {
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: large;
 height: 2.5em;
 width: 7.0em;
 border-radius: 1.875em;
 background: radial-gradient(#c2fcff, #03e9f4);
 color: #050801;
 border: 0em;
 cursor: alias;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.313em  #03e8f4, 0 0 0.313em #03e9f4, 0 0 0.313em #00f2ff,
    0 0 50px #03e9f4;
 -webkit-box-reflect: below 0 linear-gradient(transparent, #0005);
}


button:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.313em #03e9f4, 0 0 1.7em #03e9f4, 0 0  #03e9f4,
      0 0 150px #03e9f4;
}][1]][1]
```

Thanks !

Comment: The pic isn't inserted

Comment: Thank you! seems as if it didn't load the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a DIV element that provides a gradient above the image below.

Since the DIV element is below the image, We can make its position relative  and provide a negative margin, of the same height as the image, so the DIV can move above the IMAGE.

Make sure the negative margin, has the same height as the image but in negative.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

img {
  content:url(https://freepngimg.com/thumb/click_here/5-2-click-here-png-pic.png);
}

.size {
  width: 180px;
  height: 66px;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flip-vertically {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.fade-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0));
  margin-top: -66px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img id="top" class="size block">

<img id="bottom" class="size block flip-vertically">
<div class="size fade-gradient"></div>
```

I hope this helps you out. If my answer isn't what you were searching for, just let me know, so I can remove it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, sorry for the late response. Thank you so much for helping this gal out

Comment: Just wanted to share it to you on Code Pen. lmk what you think :) 

https://codepen.io/sylviamakuch-the-typescripter/pen/vYWQvwV

Comment: @SylwiaMakuch, it looks good. However, I'm a little worry about the surrounding glow around the button. I'm wondering if there is a way to add such glow to the button using CSS, instead of the image itself, or if the thickness of the glow should be reduce a little. I guess that is something for you to decided.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `box-shadow` use `drop-shadow`. Also stop using multiple elements just wrap your button in a `div` and use another div for reflection.

See the following example to understand better.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #040408;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  color: #050801;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 60rem;
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#c2fcff, #03e9f4);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.313rem #03e8f4) drop-shadow(0 0 0.313rem #03e9f4) drop-shadow(0 0 0.313rem #00f2ff) drop-shadow(0 0 50px #03e9f4);
}

.reflection {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 100% 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  color: #050801;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 60rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  background: radial-gradient(#c2fcff7a, #03e9f4de);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Hello, World!</button>
  <div class="reflection">Hello, World!</div>
</div>
```